# copy line 1 and 2 as extra columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file.txt (tab separated) that is structured like;

```
cluster01   cluster02   cluster03 ... cluster72   
typeA_1 typeA_1 type2 ...
g1_A    g4_D    g8_H
g2_B    g5_E    g9_I
g3_C    g6_F    g10_J
    g7_G    g11_K
        g12_L
```

The file has 72 columns and each column has varabile lenght

I would like to reformat the file.txt to newfile.txt like

```
g1_A    cluster01   typeA_1
g2_B    cluster01   typeA_1
g3_C    cluster01   typeA_1
g4_D    cluster02   typeA_1
g5_E    cluster02   typeA_1
g6_F    cluster02   typeA_1
g7_G    cluster02   typeA_1
g8_H    cluster03   type2
g9_I    cluster03   type2
g10_J   cluster03   type2
g11_K   cluster03   type2
g12_L   cluster03   type2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple **`awk`**+**`sed`** approach apart of how many columns do you have but nice indented 3+ rows.

```c
awk 'NR==1{split($0, clstr, /#/)} NR==2{split($0, type, /#/)}
     NR>2 {split($0, g, /#/); for (x in g) if(g[x]!="") print g[x], clstr[x], type[x]
}' <(sed -E 's/\t/#/g' infile)
```

**Explanations:**

- `NR==1{split($0, clstr, /#/)}`: We used [awk split() function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-split_0028_0029-function) which divides *string/line/record* (`$0` in awk point to whole line as *string* here) into pieces separated by hash `#` and stores in an array called `clstr`, where it's first record only with `NR==1` as condition.
- `NR==2{split($0, type, /#/)}`: This will do the same as explained above and stores in an array called `type` instead, and will run when it's second record only with `NR==2` as condition.
- `NR>2{ ... }`: This block of code will be run for the records/lines which thier **N**umber of **R**ecords are >2

  - `split($0, g, /#/)`: same as first&second items, and stores in an array called `g`.
  - `for (x in g) if(g[x]!="") print g[x], clstr[x], type[x]`: Now here we are looping over array `g` index's elements, and if its value was not null `if(g[x]!="")`, then print its value first by `g[x]`, next same indexes' value from `clstr` array and then in `type` array.

  Note that before we process the input, we replace all *tabs* with hash character `#` (You can use another character but you should make sure that is not occured in your file) then pass it to awk.

  ```
  <(sed 's/\t/#/g' infile)  ## or <(tr '\t' '#'< infile)
  ```

Input (**Tab** delimited):

```
cluster01   cluster02   cluster03   ... cluster72
typeA_1 typeA_1 type2   ...
g1_A    g4_D    g8_H
g2_B    g5_E    g9_I
g3_C    g6_F    g10_J
    g7_G    g11_K
        g12_L
```

The output:

```
g1_A cluster01 typeA_1
g4_D cluster02 typeA_1
g8_H cluster03 type2
g2_B cluster01 typeA_1
g5_E cluster02 typeA_1
g9_I cluster03 type2
g3_C cluster01 typeA_1
g6_F cluster02 typeA_1
g10_J cluster03 type2
g7_G cluster02 typeA_1
g11_K cluster03 type2
g12_L cluster03 type2
```

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution for fixed *"descending field occurrence"* from 1st to 3rd field:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {
    group1 = $1; group2 = $2; group3 = $3
}
NR == 2 {
    group1 = group1 OFS $1;
    group2 = group2 OFS $2;
    group3 = group3 OFS $3
}
NR > 2 {
    if (NF == 3) { cl1[NR - 2] = $1 }
    if (NF >= 2) { cl2[NR - 2] = $(NF - 1) }
    cl3[NR - 2] = $(NF)
}
END {
    traverse(cl1, group1);
    traverse(cl2, group2);
    traverse(cl3, group3)
}
function traverse(cl, gr) {
    len = length(cl);
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        print cl[i], gr
    }
}' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
g1  cluster01   typeA
g2  cluster01   typeA
g3  cluster01   typeA
g4  cluster02   typeA
g5  cluster02   typeA
g6  cluster02   typeA
g7  cluster02   typeA
g8  cluster03   typeB
g9  cluster03   typeB
g10 cluster03   typeB
g11 cluster03   typeB
g12 cluster03   typeB
```

Comment: Couldn't get it work below the output    
$ ~ cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
 cluster28 cf_putative
ctg15_orf200 cluster29 cf_putative
ctg15_orf201 cluster29 cf_putative The file has 72 clusters, it looks like the order it messed up!